# I want to print comments related to run scored by the batsman given in the list

Tags: python

Ques:
Given the list `kkr_runs = [4, 10, 12, 1, 28, 0, 31, 2, 6, 2, 4]`
It should print:

"good job" if the score is more than 30
"You can do better" if the score is greater than 20 but less than 30
"Ok you did something" if the score is more than 10 and less than or equal to 20
"Duck" if it's 0
"Come on!" if it's more than 0 and less than or equal to 10

I am printing the following code but getting wrong results?

```
kkr_runs = [4, 10, 12, 1, 28, 0, 31, 2, 6, 2, 4]
r=[]
for i in kkr_runs:

    if i>30:
        print(i,"good job")
    elif i>20 & i<30:
        print(i,"YOu can do better")
    elif i>10 & i<=20:
        print(i,"Ok you did something")
    elif i==0:
        print(i,"Duck")
    else:
        print(i,"Come on")
```

Comment: `&` is a Bitwise operator: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

Comment: You could use `and` or just `20 < i < 30` and `10 < i <= 20`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, logical AND is denoted by `and`.
Do something like this,

```
kkr_runs = [4, 10, 12, 1, 28, 0, 31, 2, 6, 2, 4]
r=[] 
for i in kkr_runs:
    if i>30:
        print(i,"good job")
    elif i>20 and i<30:
        print(i,"YOu can do better")
    elif i>10 and i<=20:
        print(i,"Ok you did something")
    elif i==0:
        print(i,"Duck")
    else:
        print(i,"Come on")
```

Output:

```
4 Come on
10 Come on
12 Ok you did something
1 Come on
28 YOu can do better
0 Duck
31 good job
2 Come on
6 Come on
2 Come on
4 Come on
```

Comment: Why not `20 < i < 30`?

Comment: @Nick please accept this answer if this worked well for you.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch yes this is short code but does it affect performance ? If it does't, then both are same.

Comment: Both do the same and even if there is a performance difference, it would be irrelevant for this type or program. I pointed it out because of better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if i>30:
    print(i,"good job")
elif i>20 and i<30:
    print(i,"YOu can do better")
elif i>10 and i<=20:
    print(i,"Ok you did something")
elif i==0:
    print(i,"Duck")
else:
    print(i,"Come on")
```